# How to pass user input list to the prediction model

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to implement the prediction of heart disease problem. Upon asking the user to enter the values, I am having trouble sending it to the prediction model, thus to get an output.

```py
  age = input('Enter age: ')
  sex = input('Enter sex: ')
  cp = input('Enter chest pain type: ')
  trestbps = input('Enter resting systolic blood pressure: ')
```

How do I send these user input value to get the outcome in LR which is already trained?

```py
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    lr = LogisticRegression()
    lr.fit(x_train.T,y_train.T)
    y_pred = lr.predict(x_test.T)
    print(accuracy_score(y_test.T,y_pred)*100)
```

Comment: you want to use the data for training or prediction?

Comment: The question is not very clear.

Comment: The model has already been trained. I want the user input values to be used as a predicting parameters now. How could we pass those values to the model?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to first convert these values to float point numbers since the `input` function takes the input as strings. This can be done as follows.

```
age = float(input('Enter age: '))
sex = float(input('Enter sex: '))
cp = float(input('Enter chest pain type: '))
trestbps = float(input('Enter resting systolic blood pressure: '))
```

Now the LR model expects x_test to be a list of list for `lr.predict` function. You can concatenate these values into a Python list and wrap around another list if you just have one sample to test.

```
x_test = [[age, sex, cp, trestbps]] # there could be multiple lists within the outer list if there were more than one samples
```

Depending on how your model was trained, the order of listing these variables can be different.

Comment: ```pythonuser_data = [[age,sex,cp,trestbps,chol,fbs,restecg,thalach,exang,oldpeak,slope,ca,thal]]

Comment: Thanks, glad you found the answer helpful @Amrit, please accept the answer if you found it helpful. :)